# CSS Bug For Floating Menu Commands?

Tags: html, css

http://jsbin.com/ewipi3

Basically, it should work... shouldn't it?

The sample CSS is simple:

```
command,a {float:left;border:1px solid blue;}
```

And then the HTML is also simple:

```
<menu>
   <command>Example</command>
   <command>Example</command>
   <command>Example</command>
</menu>
<br style="clear:both">
<a href="#example">Example</a>
<a href="#example">Example</a>
<a href="#example">Example</a>
```

If you guys think this is also a bug ill submit a bug report.

Oops! sorry! I meant to say Chrome and Firefox 4!
http://jsbin.com/ewipi3/6

It should look like this in those browsers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNgHE.png

Basically, text is outside the elements.

Comment: The question never explains what you think *should* be happening. It looks like it's rendering correctly to me.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Uh... haha, it's not floating at all :) http://jsbin.com/ewipi3/6  (ive made the boxes bigger for ya...

Comment: Which browser? All of them? I don't see a question here.

Comment: oops, i DID leave that detail out. Chrome and Firefox, safari appears to be working.

Comment: Looks fine in IE7 too. What browser is it *not* working in?

Comment: See my last comment & the updated post from a bit ago, but, Chrome and Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't look like this?

[image]

And should look like this?

[image]

See it working [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/StZM3/).

---

BTW I not sure if I understood you answer correctly, please comment if otherwise!

Comment: Exactly the issue (thanks!) but <other> isn't valid HTML ;) and im using HTML5 which redefined the <menu> element which (unless you know otherwise and if so let me know) needs <command>s inside

Comment: @Oscar I'm checking it out I don't have any immediate answer since I'm not too familiar with `<command>`

Comment: @Oscar if you want to, you could use my screenshots in you question to make it clearer.

Comment: Indeed, i added a link to the image :) Thanks!

Comment: @Oscar I think the command is not (yet?) supported on chrome, that might be the problem See this simple example, works on safari, doesn't in chrome! http://www.jsfiddle.net/StZM3/3/ I'm looking for documentation.

Comment: Well, the main issue i see is that browsers are supposed to still render DOM elements whether they exist or not (for forward compatibility... like this!). It's rendering them, but it's totally screwed up, and as you've shown, simple click events don't work, etc.

Comment: @Oscar I'll check by in a while.